# Redirect .asp pages to home page of my new site

Tags: .htaccess

I changed my website from .asp pages to Joomla which uses .php. The page structure has not been maintained. Now, I would like to have all traffic coming in from the indexed .asp pages (by the search engines) redirected to the home page of my site.
I have used the following Rewrite rule

> RewriteRule \.asp$ ^/index.php [R=301,L]

but the rule redirects to
https://example.com/home/example/public_html/index.php?key=1234

How can I simply remove the /home/example/public_html/ and also the ?key=1234 parameter while performing the redirect. Or simply saying, how can I just have the redirect go to the home page of my new site.
Thanks.

Comment: Clear cache and make sure some other rule is not working before.

Answer (score 0):

First see this picture from Apache below :

[image]

So , a substitution could not contains `Regular Expression` as you did here `^/index.php` this `^` should be removed first then see what you want to do .

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html

Replace your code by this :

```
RewriteRule \.asp$   http://example.com? [R=301,L]
```

I put `?` after example.com to prevent query string like `key=1234` to be appended in new target .

**Note:** clear browser cache then test it .

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.